# Gravitational field strength to distance graph

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets

Can someone please explain why the graph is linear from the start to the surface?
[image]

Comment: What is that graph for? Can you provide higher resolutions of it?

Comment: Magnitude of gravitational field to distance from centre of sphere.

Comment: Use Gauss's law. The enclosed mass grows with $r^3$, but the area of the Gaussian surface increases with $r^2$ so there remains $r$. Got it?

Comment: what does the graph mean?

Answer (score 0):

From Gauss's law for gravity we have:

$$\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\mathbf{g}\cdot d\mathbf{a}=-G M_{enc}$$

$$\frac1{4\pi}g(r)\cdot4\pi r^2=-G\rho\cdot\frac 43\pi r^3$$

$$\mathbf{g}(r)=-\frac43\pi\rho G r \mathbf{\hat r}$$